# Increase `emmeans` comparison arrows' thickness

Tags: r, ggplot2, emmeans

I'm looking for a slick way to increase the arrows' thickness. My rough idea is with `geom_line(aes(size = 5))`.  I did not get thicker arrows, but a new legend.

How do I change my code? Thanks a lot.

```
 warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)
 warp.emm <- emmeans(warp.lm, ~ tension | wool)
plot(warp.emm, by = NULL, comparisons = TRUE, adjust = "mvt", 
   horizontal = FALSE, colors = c("darkgreen")) +
  geom_line(aes(size = 5))
```

[image]

This code, `geom_line(arrow(size = 5))` returned an error: `Error in arrow(size = 5) : unused argument (size = 5)`

How do I change my code? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you a legend because you mapped on the `size` aes instead of using size as an argument, i.e. outside of `aes()`. Second, you get an error because `arrow()` has no size argument. See `?arrow`.

Instead you could increase the size of the arrows like so:

```r
library(emmeans)
library(ggplot2)
warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)
warp.emm <- emmeans(warp.lm, ~ tension | wool)
g <- plot(warp.emm, by = NULL, comparisons = TRUE, adjust = "mvt", 
     horizontal = FALSE, colors = c("darkgreen"))
```

Inspecting the ggplot object we see that it's composed of five layers, where the arrows are drawn via the `geom_segment` layers 3 and 4:

```r
g$layers
#> [[1]]
#> geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#> position_identity 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> mapping: xend = ~ucl, yend = ~pri.fac, x = ~lcl, y = ~pri.fac 
#> geom_segment: arrow = NULL, arrow.fill = NULL, lineend = butt, linejoin = round, na.rm = FALSE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#> position_identity 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> mapping: xend = ~lcmpl, yend = ~pri.fac, x = ~the.emmean, y = ~pri.fac 
#> geom_segment: arrow = list(angle = 30, length = 0.07, ends = 2, type = 2), arrow.fill = NULL, lineend = butt, linejoin = round, na.rm = FALSE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#> position_identity 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> mapping: xend = ~rcmpl, yend = ~pri.fac, x = ~the.emmean, y = ~pri.fac 
#> geom_segment: arrow = list(angle = 30, length = 0.07, ends = 2, type = 2), arrow.fill = NULL, lineend = butt, linejoin = round, na.rm = FALSE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#> position_identity 
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
#> stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
#> position_identity
```

Hence, to increase the thickness of the arrows you can set `size` parameter of these layers like so:

```r
g$layers[[3]]$aes_params$size = 1.5
g$layers[[4]]$aes_params$size = 1.5

g
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I also know now how to modify the shades. :)